# How to call drawRect: method in super view from subview?

Tags: objective-c, reload, drawrect, superview

I am showing a popover from a custom view like this:

[image]

And when the user taps on the popover I must draw something on my custom view (from which the popover is shown).

I try to make `[myPopover.view.superView setNeedsDisplay];` but it don't work.
May be I can try more anything for reload my super view or call in it `drawRect:` method?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this? `[myPopover.superView drawRect:]`

Comment: Since when is it recommended to call `drawRect:` directly?